# How to merge multiple rows in Excel if rows numbers vary?

Tags: excel

I have the current spreadsheet as display in the picture, I'd like to merge 
all the rows of the notes so the item number and the notes ties in on row.
I have at least 5000 records of item and the number of rows varies based on item
, I can't manually do the formula so I'd like see if there is an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Link to the picture is below:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/127513185@N07/

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't manually do the formula" ?

Comment: As I have a around 5000 records and the number of rows for notes vary.

Answer (score 0):

my answer requires MOREFUNC addon*

[image]

first create a column that will hold the "item id" next to each "note":
Add a column between B&C (this is now column C). In cell `C2` type : `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),C1,B2)` copy down to the bottom.

once you have Morfunc up and running use the following formula in cell `E2`: `{=MCONCAT(IF($C$2:$C$10=B2,$D$2:$D$10,""),"-")}` Notice the curly braces. This is an array formula you have to confirm using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, not just `Enter`

then copy the formula to `E3:E10`

now copy the whole column E, right click the selection, and select `paste special` and `values`

you can now remove columns C, D as well as all the rows that do not have an "item id" (you can do this by using a filter where B is empty, select allrows, right click, delete row).

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)